# Integral Area between curves

Tags: calculus, integration, area

$f(x) = {e^x}$

$g(x) = {e^{ - x}}$

Calculate area between functions $f,g$ and lines $x =  - 1,x = 1$.

Solution

Symmetrics $f,g$ or  $\int\limits_{ - 1}^0 {f(x) - g(x)dx - \int\limits_0^1 {f(x) - g(x)dx = ...} }$

I found  $\frac{(1 - e)^2}{e}$
Right answer?

Comment: You should add the two integrals I think, not subtract them because you want to combine the area between x=-1 and x=0 with the area between x=0 and x=1 to get the total area between x-1 and x=1. I didn't do integral calculus long time ago, but I guess it you should add the two integral, not subtract them. Can someone verify this?

Comment: It's 2 times that. Also, $f<g$ on $(-1,0)$ and $f>g$ on $(0,1)$, which is the opposite of what you have.

Comment: @KKZiomek You are missing that they are keeping the ordering the same whereas one will dominate in the negative and the other in the positive. I think the real issue is they flipped which is which.

Comment: $2\int_0^1(e^x-e^{-x})dx$ this is a way

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is symmetric but you need to be careful with which function is greater than the other. As @mrob says, $f<g$ on $(-1,0)$ and $f>g$ on $(0,1)$, you really want to answer

$\int_{-1}^0 [g(x)-f(x)]\, dx + \int_0^1 [f(x)-g(x)] \, dx$

You add them since the areas are above the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the mathematica site, but...

```
 f[x_] := e^x
 g[x_] := e^-x

 root := x /. Solve[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals]
 root
 = 0

 Integrate[g[x] - f[x], {x, -1, root[[1]]}]
 Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, root[[1]], 1}]

 = {-2 + 1/e + e}, {-2 + 1/e + e}
```

As stated, they are symmetric so you could just integrate one of them and multiply by 2

$$2*(-2 + 1/e + e)$$ = 
**$$-4 + 2/e + 2e$$**

Comment: Very interesting.